# Loading UPI app with VPA & AMOUNT from browser

Tags: php, payment-gateway, payment-processing, google-pay, upi

I have made a php based website and working on payment integration now.
I want to add upi payment option with paytm, google pay, phonepe and bhim.
Once user clicks on icon, appropriate app with predefined VPA and AMOUNT should get loaded

Please help

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Further, please read the [Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist). Also learn how to post [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1):

The way to do this is to follow the [UPI linking specification (page 5)](https://www.npci.org.in/sites/default/files/UPI%20Linking%20Specs_ver%201.6.pdf).

Assuming that the link will be presented on a mobile web browser, your link should look something like: `upi://pay?pa=<VPA>&am=<AMOUNT>`

Answer (score 1):

You can integrate the UPI intent solution provided by paytm. This will work fine in mobile view, through this integration you will get the deeplink. 
You need to call the deeplink provided which will invoke all the UPI PSP Apps on the device and shown to the user with payment amount already filled.
Just for your information UPI intent will not work in web/desktop. You can integrate UPI collect to support web/desktop payment.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a link like `upi://pay?pa=<VPA>&am=<AMOUNT> (paytmmp://pay?pa=<VPA>&am=<AMOUNT>` for Paytm, etc) and use `window.location.href` to open the UPI app.

Please note that you will need a merchant account to make the transaction successful.